# Why is Blender cancelling my render on "undo"

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, interface, shortcut

Everytime a render is processing, while I'm doing other things in the software, and want to undo my last action, Blender cancels the ongoing render.

I thought it was a shortcut issue, but it's not; when I'm clicking on "undo", it also cancels the ongoing render, whatever my last action was.

Does anyone have a clue on how to prevent that?

It seems like I've been suffering from this issue since I installed Blender. I don't think it's a version / update issue.

I'm currently running Blender 3.3 on macOS.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't "do other things in the software" (assuming you mean in Blender itself) while Blender is rendering a scene. Ctrl-Z (undo) or Esc will cancel the render if the Blender executable has the focus.

Comment: I think John Eason is right, sounds like it's working as intended. You could work around this by opening up another window of Blender and working on your file in there? If you do, be careful with what you save and don't save.

Comment: I don't know anything about Macs, but you can certainly open another instance of Blender under Windows. However you wouldn't be able to work on the same file while rendering it in the other instance of course.

Comment: Then just work on a copy of the file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers.

I can "do other things in the software", it works well, I can't just undo one of them while a render is ongoing.


Isn't it essential to be able to continue to work while waiting for a long render?
For me, seems like most of the render-based software has this ability..!

Comment: Yes and no. Many DCC softwares actually have quite a disconnection with the renderer. Some even prevent you from working on the same file currently being used for rendering. The main issue being that having it change while rendering can cause unexpected results or crashes. In production, the rendering process is most often done on a separate file, and on a separate machine. To avoid conflicts, among other things.

Comment: Sure, I understand. But in that case, what seems kind of weird with Blender is that you CAN work in the file, save it, make edits... while a render is going.

Just the "undo" action is attributed to the current rendering process, which I find kind of weird and useless, because the rest of the software keeps the "focus" on the usual actions.

Would be great to be able to just unlink the "undo" from the "render" process.

Comment: Try posting it as a feature proposal on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=new#). If it was up to me, Blender shouldn't allow to work on the render file at all. It should either block the UI while rendering (with the added benefit of better render times), or completely dissociate the rendering from the current open session (not just Ctrl Z, Esc too). Could be an option. Could also be tied to whether you chose to output the render in a new window or not. Anyway that gets out of topic on BSE x)